# Dynamically add number of options in a Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a number value which is coming from my database. I want to display a dropdown list based on the count of the number. For example if the number is 5 then i need to display 1-5 options in dropdown list. Can any one guide me on this?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: you mean if db return 3 then three <option> tag should be create ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database returns 5 and puts it in the variable "number" you could do this:

```
<form>
<select id="myid"></select>
</form>
<script>
 var number=5;
 var optionList = "";
 for (var x=1; x<=number; x++) {
  optionList += "<option>"+x+"</option>";
 }
 $("select#myid").html(optionList);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This one is exactly meets my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Please first search your thought in google. I give you example in php
If Your database give response like 5
Than write code like

```
<select>
<?php $i=5;
for($i;$i<=5;$i++)
{ 
echo "<option>".$i."</option>";
}?>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you edit your sentence "I give you example in php If Your database give response like 5 Than right code like" - I don't know what that means.

Comment: @Cleb sorry for that. My english very poor bcoz my native language is not english so

Answer (score 0):

There are number of way you can do it some of them are

```
$('select').append($('<option>', {value:1, text:'One'}));
```

or

```
  $('select').append('<option val="1">One</option>');
```

or

```
 var option = new Option(text, value);
    $('select').append($(option));
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternate solution for @theglossy1 solution.
This is useful when you want to concatenate large no. of options,
use array for string Concatenation

```
<form>
<select id="myid"></select>
</form>
<script>
 var number=5;
 var ArrayoptionList = []; //Array of Option list
 for (var x=1; x<=number; x++) {
  ArrayoptionList.push("<option>"+x+"</option>");
 }
 $("select#myid").html(ArrayoptionList.join(""));
</script>
```

Refer below link

[High Performance Concatenation in Javascript](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-fast-string-concatenation/)